# Derivation of partial derivative of cost function with respect to weights in backpropagation algorithm

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I am studying Machine Learning from Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on coursera. I am stuck at understanding math behind back propagation.

Here is an image of backpropagation algorithm from his course.
[image: Here is the image of backpropagation algorithm which I am studying] 
I am able to understand the derivation of $\delta$ terms from his [course notes](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/resources/EcbzQ) but the derivation of $\Delta^{(l)}=\Delta^{(l)}+\delta^{(l+1)}(a^{(l)})^{T}$ is not given.

**My questions:**

1. What is the meaning of $\Delta^{(l)}$ and how is $\Delta^{(l)}=\Delta^{(l)}+\delta^{(l+1)}(a^{(l)})^{T}$

<strike>2. What is the meaning of $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{D_{i,j}^{(l)}}$ and how is it equal to $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{D_{i,j}^{(l)}:=\dfrac{1}{m}(\Delta_{i,j}^{(l)}+\lambda\Theta_{i,j}^{(l)})}$ if $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{j\ne0}$ and $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{D_{i,j}^{(l)}:=\dfrac{1}{m}(\Delta_{i,j}^{(l)}}$ if $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{j=0}$</strike>

<strike>3. How is $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{D_{i,j}^{(l)}=\dfrac{\partial J(\Theta)}{\partial D_{i,j}^{(l)}}}$.</strike>

EDIT:
After referring to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294873/what-is-the-significance-of-the-delta-matrix-in-neural-network-backpropagation) answer on stats.stackexchange.com I now understand that $D_{i,j}^{(l)}$ is the averaged error of weight $\Theta_{i,j}^{(l)}$ over all the training set. So the only part left which I do not understand is why are we adding $\delta^{(l+1)}(a^{(l)})^{T}$ to $\Delta^{(l)}$?

Please give answers with mathematical derivations.